# Can't uninstall MS office 15 trial

Tags: windows-8, ms-office

Does anybody know what MS Office 15 is? I installed this trial version of it and now can't uninstall it after the trial has expired. It is not listed in `Control Panel > Programs`. I don't see any uninstall binary in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15

Can't get rid of it. I can't even associate .doc files with an MS Office 2003 I have installed on my machine.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I can feel your frustration, but this question is not on topic for this site, you would be better off asking it on SuperUser

Comment: Oh I forgot this is for programming. You're right I posted out of frustration. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution on a microsoft site.
Try this please:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501

If this don't work, u can try this:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/my-60-day-office-2013-trial-expired-after-about-a/4ad7a7f0-5d1e-4731-b528-bee648305a84

Regards